# Finding the twin primes up to an inputed integer. Haskell

Tags: haskell, duplicates, list-comprehension

I need to find all the twin primes up to an inputted number. After my trying it out this is the closest i can get:

```
primeTwins :: Integer -> [Integer]
primeTwins x = [y | x <- [2..x], y <- [x-2, x+2]]
```

If x is 20 prime Twins returns: [0,4,1,5,3,7,5,9,9,13,11,15,15,19,17,21]

So this returns primes +2 and primes -2 and with duplicates, However i need just twin primes (A twin prime is a prime number that is either 2 less or 2 more than another prime number) with no duplication. Ive been searching but cant find a way to sort lists. Im very new to haskell, So any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to start by looking at just *prime* numbers.

Comment: You might want to peek some efficient expression for the infinite list of prime numbers in the [relevant page of the Haskell Wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers). BTW may I suggest you add the `primes` tag to your question, in order to ease searching for future users; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it'd be nice to have an infinite list of primes:

```hs
primes :: [Integer]
primes = 2:3:filter
    (\n -> not $ any
        (\p -> n `mod` p == 0)
        (takeWhile (\p -> p * p <= n) primes))
    [5,7..]
```

This is similar to the Sieve of Eratosthenes, checking only prime factors up to the square root of the number. For reference, `take 20 primes` is `[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71]`, so it works properly. Now, we want to filter out just the twin primes into another infinite list:

```hs
infTwinPrimes :: [Integer]
-- we need to manually enter 3 5 7 since 5 is a part of two pairs
infTwinPrimes = 3:5:7:(
    -- we convert the tuple into a list
    ( >>= \(a, b) -> [a, b])
    $ filter (\(a, b) -> b - a == 2)
    -- we drop 4 to compensate for manually entering 3, 5, 7
    $ drop 4
    -- we zip primes with its tail in order to
    -- get every element in a tuple with the next element
    $ zip primes (tail primes)
    )
```

If you're confused, it might help to think about how `zip primes (tail primes)` is `[(2,3),(3,5),(5,7),(7,11),(11,13),(13,17),(17,19),...]`, and how `[(1, 2), (3, 4)] >>= \(a, b) -> [a, b]` is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. Now, our twin primes function is as easy as a `takeWhile`:

```hs
twinPrimes :: Integer -> [Integer]
twinPrimes n = takeWhile (<= n) infTwinPrimes
```

And we can verify that it works

```hs
λ> twinPrimes 20
[3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
```

Which does indeed contain every twin prime up to 20.